# Is it possible to move an SMS message to front of Message Queue in Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

If SMS messages are queued up, is it possible to send a new, high-priority message to the front of the queue so that it is delivered before the rest of the messages in the Messaging Queue?

Answer (score 1):

There is not, however queuing is per Twilio phone number, so you can have a Twilio phone number (or Copilot Messaging Service) for higher priority traffic.

You can also delete a message from a queue and set a `validityPeriod` for a message in a queue.

> How long in seconds the message can remain in our outgoing message
>   queue. After this period elapses, the message fails and we call your
>   status callback. Can be between 1 and the default value of 14,400
>   seconds. After a message has been accepted by a carrier, however, we
>   cannot guarantee that the message will not be queued after this
>   period. We recommend that this value be at least 5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you. I did see those options, but I prefer all the messages come from the same number so the recipient knows they're from the same sender. And I don't want to delete any of the existing queued messages. Was just hoping there was a way to jump the queue.